# Having issue with my html form in a php page

Tags: php, forms

I have tried to put this code in my webpage but I have this error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in E:\MyServer\htdocs\...(line 1 from this script)
```

CODE :

```
<form action='delete.php?name="<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>"' method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

this code is in a .php page
Thanks.

Comment: `<form action="delete.php?name=<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
</form>`

Comment: can you post more of your code? i expect it is wrapped in an "echo"?

Answer (score 2):

Try to format it properly:

```
<form action="delete.php?name=<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

How to get the value you pass through your form:

`Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>`.

**EDIT**

Also you should add this in `delete.php` file:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){ $name = $_POST['name']; }
```

See : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop the double quotes around the variable name and move them to the actual element property.

```
<form action='delete.php?name="<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>"'
                              ^                               ^
```

It then becomes

```
<form action="delete.php?name=<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="delete.php?name=<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

This should work ..

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to send the data via GET and POST to delete.php?

```
<form action='delete.php' method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
```

With this you can then just do $_POST['name'] to get your contact name...

Sorry if I have missed something but cannot see why you would need it passed twice

Comment: i have make the change but now i have this errro : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in 
I forgot to say: this code is in a Print sintax 
Print "all my code above"

Comment: @user3698856 Please elaborate properly your question. Write what exactly you want to do.

Comment: As SJD said can you provide more information and maybe the rest of the code you are running?

Comment: i want to send name via get and post for delete him from database.. i have already code for delete.php but i have error in value statement...(here : value="<?php echo $contact['name']; ?>")

Comment: That section of code looks fine, from the looks of you error you are printing the form via php?

try either ' . $contact['name'] . ' OR " . $contact['name'] . " in place of <?php echo $contact['name']; ?>

Comment: ok this $contact['name'] work but now in my delete.php page i must to change how to get this value and i don't know :) you can help me ?

Comment: to get the value from the hidden element for example:

$contact_name = $_POST['name'];

Comment: @user3698856 You should study a tutorial to learn how a form in PHP works. I dropped a link in my reply.

Comment: still don't work .. he said to me "Undefined index: name in E:\MyServer\htdocs...."

Comment: <?php session_start();
 $contact_name = $_POST['email'];
.....
?> and this is my delete.php begin code

Comment: As SJD said you need to read up a little more on php forms, posting the whole code will make things much easier for people to help you as the error is not in the section you have shown here.

Comment: @user3698856 note that your first input is "hidden" type so you're passing an "hidden" parameter and need to check if it is empty using `isset` function. As I said, you'd better study a tutorial.

Comment: i have tried to do this in my delete.php page if(isset($_POST['name'])){ $name = $_POST['name']; } but isset($_POST['name']) appear to be hidder or empty and the program stop without enter in if body .... so i searched on the net but i found nothing...

Comment: Change the `<input>` type into text, not hidden.